# setInterval for running a function with if statement not working

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, setinterval

I need to use the `setInterval` function to run the function `change()` after every 3 seconds but what I have tried so far is not working:

```js
    var image = document.getElementById("gif1");
    var image_tracker = '1gif' ; 
    function change() { 
     if(image_tracker =='1gif') { 
         image.src='2.gif' ; 
      image_tracker = '2gif' ; }
    else if (image_tracker ='2gif') { 
         image.src='3.gif' ; 
      image_tracker = '3gif' ; }
    else if (image_tracker = '3gif') {
         image.src='1gif' ; 
      image_tracker = '1gif' ; } }
    
    var timer = setInterval ('change () ; ' , 3000 ) ;
```

```html
<img src="1.gif" id="gif1" alt="1.gif" style="width:400px;height:400px;border:1px solid black;">
```

Comment: The function is not working at all , the starting picture is just static in my page . :/

Comment: ( please ignore the whole <div>...</div> template , i didnt' delete it due to being in a hurry .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bunch of syntax errors all over your code:

1. Your `elseif` conditions are [assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) `=` and should be replaced with a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) such as the *loose equality operator* `==` or the *strict equality operator* `===` depending on your requirement [Check this [article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a) for an in-depth explanation of the differences between the two].
2. You are assigning your `setInterval()` to a variable thus preventing it from running.
3. You are referencing a string called `change()` inside your `setInterval()`. Remove the quotes since change is a function.

---

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/hk5pvfdo/10/) or the **Code Snippet** below to see the gif change every 3 seconds:

```js
var img = document.getElementById("gif1");

var image_tracker = '1gif';

function change() { 
 if(image_tracker == '1gif') { 
     img.src = '//media.giphy.com/media/13gvXfEVlxQjDO/giphy.gif'; 
     image_tracker = '2gif' ; }
 else if (image_tracker == '2gif') { 
     img.src= '//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif'; 
     image_tracker = '3gif' ; }
 else if (image_tracker == '3gif') {
     img.src = '//colinbendell.cloudinary.com/image/upload/c_crop,f_auto,g_auto,h_350,w_400/v1512090971/Wizard-Clap-by-Markus-Magnusson.gif'; 
     image_tracker = '1gif' ;
 }
}

setInterval(change , 3000 ) ;
```

```html
<img src="//colinbendell.cloudinary.com/image/upload/c_crop,f_auto,g_auto,h_350,w_400/v1512090971/Wizard-Clap-by-Markus-Magnusson.gif" id="gif1" alt="1.gif" style="width:400px;height:400px;border:1px solid black;" />
```

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work like that . Same issue as before , the first picture is just static in my page . Thanks for the answer

Comment: Please reproduce what you have in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) with live links to images and I'll check it out.

Comment: Its `img.src = '2.gif'` not `img.src('2.gif')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it finally worked , my last trouble is that when it reaches the 3rd gif i'd like it to go back to the 1st one and keep changing .

Comment: Glad I could help man. And regarding the gif rotation, check the jsFiddle link in the comment above as well as the code snippet above. The gifs automatically rotates back to the first one once the last one is reached. Compare your current code with mine and see if you left anything out.